# How do I connect to Icecast with Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, streaming, icecast, pydub

For the past few days I've been trying to stream audio from Python to Icecast, but it simply refused connection.

Here's the code:

```py
import requests
from pydub import AudioSegment
import base64

login = "admin"
password = "hackme"
auth = base64.b64encode(f"{login}:{password}".encode()).decode()

# Download and encode an audio file
AudioSegment.converter = "C://ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe"
AudioSegment.ffprobe = "C://ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe"
audio = AudioSegment.from_file("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Stuff/Coding_Stuff/PythonPlayer/testsong.mp3")
audio = audio.set_frame_rate(44100) # Set the sample rate
audio = audio.set_channels(2) # Set the number of channels
audio = audio.export(format="mp3", bitrate="128k") # Export to MP3 format with a bitrate of 128 kbps

# Preparing data for the request
url = "http://localhost:8000/stream" 
headers = {
     "Content-Type": "audio/mpeg", 
     "Authorization": f"Basic {auth}",
     "User-Agent": "Admin",
     "Ice-Public": "1", 
     "Ice-Name": "TestStream", 
     "Ice-Description": "stream", 
     "Ice-URL": "http://example.com", 
     "Ice-Genre": "1" 
}

# Sending a request to the icecast server
response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=audio)

# Checking response status
if response.status_code == 200:
     print("Stream started successfully")
else:
     print("Stream failed: ", response.reason)

# Change stream metadata
metadata_url = "http://localhost:8000/admin/metadata"
metadata_params = {
     "mount": "/stream", 
     "mode": "updinfo", 
     "song": "42" 
}
metadata_response = requests.get(metadata_url, headers=headers, params=metadata_params)

# Checking response status
if metadata_response.status_code == 200:
     print("Metadata updated successfully")
else:
     print("Metadata update failed: ", metadata_response.reason)
```

Here's the error it gave:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Stuff\Coding_Stuff\PythonPlayer\pythonplayer.py", line 31, in <module>
    response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=audio)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 130, in put
    return request("put", url, data=data, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 501, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide.

I tried to connect to icecast. It didn't connect.